# How can I get URL Frontend in Backend Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

For example: I'm in URL `http://localhost:3000/admin/posts` (Front-end) and send request to URL `http://localhost:8080/test/user` (Backend). How can I get URL Frontend while I'm in backend?

Comment: Can you describe the question a bit more? 1. You are asking how can you get the frontend response to the Backend? 2. You are asking how you can access the frontend URL in the Backend? I'm not quite sure which one of these you are trying to ask, Kindly provide some more information about what you are trying to do or try to describe the question according to what you want.

Comment: I use ReactJS to build Frontend and Spring boot to build API. When I'm in Spring boot, I want to know which Frontend URL just send request to Spring boot

Comment: As per me, unless you wrap your front-end URL to any of properties you are sending to backend, it might be difficult.

Comment: The main reason why we make an independent Backend by using Spring boot is so that we can use the same backend services with different UI. You can use the same backend services on the web as well as on mobile. You would not be able to know which URL has sent s request you would only know which API  has been triggered and what it has sent as a parameter value or object. Let me know if I have cleared your query or else provide some use case where you would want to know which URL has a request, If you want to know if /home/user has a request or /home/admin as requested then it's a different story

Comment: If the case which I have mentioned is what you want then you will have to add spring security to your application and from there you will have to provide a list of users to it along with the roles provided to that user which you allow you to perform some basic Authentication and Authorization, But even here you won't know which URL has requested the API you would only know which user is requesting and if that user has the correct authorization rights or not. Watch this playlist to learn spring-security- [link](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTYTEooakHchTGglSvkZAjnE).